# How to get the prompt to run before `gets`

Tags: ruby

I wrote this code:

```
puts "what is your name"
name = gets.chomp
```

When I run this in the terminal, I have to enter the name before the prompt starts.

How can I make the prompt start before I enter the name?

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: The code above works okay for you?

Comment: Yes. ..........

Comment: What if you use `STDIN.gets.chomp` and `STDOUT.puts` instead?

Comment: Or, what is your `STDIN` and `STDOUT` values?

Comment: I am still getting the same issue. Am gonna be driving in a few minutes, I'll try and do it in a new project maybe I have some other actors affecting the code